# Mudar cor da imagem com CSS

Tags: css

É possível mudar a cor de uma imagem com CSS? Aplicando um filtro talvez, ou algo parecido. Tem como? Por exemplo, uma imagem assim: https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/06/02/16/14/tablet-1431399_960_720.png

Comment: Lucas, que tipo de filtro você quer aplicar? inverte as cores? preto e branco? escala de cinza?

Comment: Detalhes, precisamos de detalhes.

Comment: É, digamos que no mínimo preto e branco. Essa imagem por exemplo, é possível por ela branca, somente com cSS?

Comment: Tenho uma ideia que acho que funciona pra colocar a cor que vc quiser apenas com CSS e uma unica imagem e até trocar a cor em runtime com jquery se precisar.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Existem 3 maneiras (ou 4~5):

### Filtros CSS

O CSS tem a propriedade `filter` suportado por todos navegadores modernos, veja no [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#search=CSS%20Filter%20Effects), no entanto o Edge não suporta o valor com `url()` e Opera mini e Internet Explorer 11 não tem suporte, exemplos que ajudam a colorir:

| Valores | Descrição |
| --- | --- |
| `filter: url("filters.svg#filter-id");` | Adiciona um filtro baseado em um SVG, no firefox antes este era o único suportado, assim que possível irei editar com detalhes sobre este especificamente |
| `filter: brightness(.4);` | Muda o brilho |
| `filter: contrast(200%);` | Muda o contraste |
| `filter: grayscale(50%);` | Muda o nível de cinza |
| `filter: invert(75%);` | Inverte as cores, baseado em porcentagem |
| `filter: opacity(25%);` | Muda a opacidade |
| `filter: saturate(30%);` | Muda a saturação |
| `filter: sepia(60%);` | Muda o "tom" de sépia |

Eles podem ser combinados:

```
filter: contrast(175%) brightness(3%);
```

Tem outros filtros, mas geralmente são de sombra.

> Os valores em porcentagem podem ser usado com `%`, o equivalente:
> `.5` será o mesmo `50%` e `100%` será o mesmo `1` (`1.0`)

Eles podem ser combinados:

```
filter: contrast(1.75) brightness(.3);
```

### Trocar o background-image

Criando duas imagens pode alternar usando CSS

Por exemplo com hover:

```
<style>
.bg {
     background: url(../images/foto-vermelha.jpg) no-repeat;
     width: 300px;
     height: 300px;
}
.bg:hover {
     background-image: url(../images/foto-azul.jpg);
}
</style>

<div class="bg"></div>
```

Ou com classe extra (para usar coisas como `Element.classList.toggle` do JavaScript):

```
<style>
.bg {
     background: url(../images/foto-vermelha.jpg) no-repeat;
     width: 300px;
     height: 300px;
}
.bg-azul {
     background-image: url(../images/foto-azul.jpg);
}
</style>

<div class="bg"></div> <!-- mostra a foto em cores vermelhas -->
<div class="bg bg-azul"></div> <!-- mostra a foto em cores azuis -->
```

### Trocar o background-position (CSS Sprite)

O CSS Sprite é uma técnica que pode combinar múltiplas imagens para trocar a foto mudando a posição da imagem no background, a imagem deve ser semelhante a estrela, o checked e alguns outros usam (esta imagem é do proprio SOpt):

> [image: sprites SOpt]

Um exemplo:

```css
.css-sprite {
    background:  url(https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/br/img/sprites.svg?v=554232ea0d79) -5px -120px no-repeat;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
}

.css-sprite:hover {
    background-position: -45px -120px;
}
```

```html
<div class="css-sprite"></div>
```

> Tem mais 2, ambos com SVG, um utiliza `#target` e o outro utiliza `fill` (já que a imagem seria um vetor), assim que possível adiciono um exemplo.

Answer (score 6):

você tem duas opções, usando CSS (porem tem pouco suporte por parte dos navegadores) ou aplicando um filtro sobre o SVG.

**Filtro CSS:**

```css
img {
  width: 300px;
  filter: grayscale(1)
}
```

```html
<img src="http://abhiyantri.com/wp-content/uploads/stackoverflow2.jpg" />
```

**Filtro SVG:**

```css
img {
  width: 300px;
  filter: url(svg#grayscale)
}
```

```html
<img src="http://abhiyantri.com/wp-content/uploads/stackoverflow2.jpg" />
<svg>
  <filter id="grayscale">
    <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0"/>
  </filter>
</svg>
```

**Agora vou alterar os canais no filtro.:**

```css
img {
  float: left;
  width: 300px;
}

#img0 {
  filter: url(svg#normal)
}

#img1 {
  filter: url(svg#grayscale)
}

#img2 {
  filter: url(svg#redscale)
}

#img3 {
  filter: url(svg#greenscale)
}

#img4 {
  filter: url(svg#bluescale)
}

#img5 {
  filter: url(svg#inverter_canais)
}
```

```html
<img id="img0" src="https://dncache-mauganscorp.netdna-ssl.com/thumbseg/1293/1293392-bigthumbnail.jpg" />

<img id="img1" src="https://dncache-mauganscorp.netdna-ssl.com/thumbseg/1293/1293392-bigthumbnail.jpg" />

<img id="img2" src="https://dncache-mauganscorp.netdna-ssl.com/thumbseg/1293/1293392-bigthumbnail.jpg" />

<img id="img3" src="https://dncache-mauganscorp.netdna-ssl.com/thumbseg/1293/1293392-bigthumbnail.jpg" />

<img id="img4" src="https://dncache-mauganscorp.netdna-ssl.com/thumbseg/1293/1293392-bigthumbnail.jpg" />

<img id="img5" src="https://dncache-mauganscorp.netdna-ssl.com/thumbseg/1293/1293392-bigthumbnail.jpg" />

<svg>
  <filter id="normal">
    <feColorMatrix 
      values="1 0 0 0 0     
              0 1 0 0 0      
              0 0 1 0 0      
              0 0 0 1 0"/>
  </filter>
</svg>

<svg>
  <filter id="grayscale">
    <feColorMatrix 
      values="0.33 0.33 0.33 0 0     
              0.33 0.33 0.33 0 0      
              0.33 0.33 0.33 0 0      
              0    0    0    1 0"/>
  </filter>
</svg>

<svg>
  <filter id="redscale">
    <feColorMatrix 
      values="0.33 0.33 0.33 0 0
              0    0    0    0 0      
              0    0    0    0 0      
              0    0    0    1 0"/>
  </filter>
</svg>

<svg>
  <filter id="greenscale">
    <feColorMatrix 
      values="0    0    0    0 0  
              0.33 0.33 0.33 0 0
              0    0    0    0 0      
              0    0    0    1 0"/>
  </filter>
</svg>

<svg>
  <filter id="bluescale">
    <feColorMatrix 
      values="0    0    0    0 0  
              0    0    0    0 0  
              0.33 0.33 0.33 0 0
              0    0    0    1 0"/>
  </filter>
</svg>

<svg>
  <filter id="inverter_canais">
    <feColorMatrix 
      values="0   0.5 0.5 0 0  
              0.5 0   0.5 0 0  
              0.5 0.5 0   0 0
              0   0   0   1 0"/>
  </filter>
</svg>
```

Answer (score -1):

Consegui, usando o filter: `invert(100%)` a imagem inverte a cor, no caso de preto, vai pra branco. Deixei a resposta pra ajudar mais pessoas que precisem.

Comment: Por quê não aproveita e faz um [mcve]?

Comment: Eu não sei usar aquela função de executar aqui do SO, poderia me passar Anderson?

Comment: Lucas: https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/